# Create dialog with y scrolling

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using a dialog to show users information. So I populate it with a `div`.

```
function showPopup(elem)
        {
            var orig = $($(elem).siblings()[0]);
            var populDiv = $('<div title="Indicators">').append(orig.clone().show());
            var dialog = populDiv.dialog(
                {
                    closeOnEscape: true,
                    width: 'auto',
                    resizable: true,
                    beforeClose: function (event, ui) {
                        orig.replaceWith(populDiv.children().eq(0).hide());
                    }
                });
        }
```

The problem is that the content of the `div` I use is dynamic: users can click on buttons (inside the dialog) to view hidden elements.

What I want is for the dialog to change it's width to fit the content and to be able to scroll vertically as well as the ability to resize it.

So I've set `overflow-y:scroll` to the parent `div` but it doesn't seem to be aware of the size of the dialog and clips out of it. What to do?

PS: The hidden divs inside the dialog also have `overflow-x:scroll` because of their high width.

Answer (score 1):

Why not set the `height` of the dialog box instead , So you can get the intended scroll bar as required ,

```
  $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Modal",
        height: 250,
        width: 400,
```

Or you can use `maxHeight` , `maxWidth` , `minHeight` or `minWidth` as required.

See : http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-maxHeight

#### See a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvjj8/4691/)

Comment: I actually used: `resizable: true, modal: true, width: 'auto'` and it works. Not sure why the height also ajusts.